# fatal error: opencv2/core/core.hpp caffe framework installation

Tags: linux, nvidia, caffe, pycaffe

I'm trying to install Caffe framework with this script: https://gist.github.com/jetsonhacks/acf63b993b44e1fb9528 and I'm getting opencv2/core/core.hpp error.

```
CXX src/caffe/layers/data_layer.cpp
src/caffe/layers/data_layer.cpp:2:33: 
 fatal error: opencv2/core/core.hpp: No such file or directory
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
                             ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [.build_release/src/caffe/layers/data_layer.o] Error 1
```

In the documentation, OpenCV is optional. But that error tells me not.
Does such `include` have nothing to do with OpenCV installation?

Comment: `I'm getting opencv2/core/core.hpp error` - What kind of error do you get? Be precise.

Answer (score 5):

Installing opencv for python is not sufficient.
You also need to do

```
sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and solved it just by installing OpenCV. You will find other similar errors, unless you have installed all prerequisites.